# Visual Studio 2013 Individual User Accounts template to use Identity 2.0, open multiple connection to database

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Regards,
I Created an ASP.NET MVC 5 Website using the template of Visual Studio 2013 with Individual User Accounts to use Identity 2.0.
Also, I follow the instructions (http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) for changing the Entity Framework layer to use Dapper.
Everything worked fine, the only issue is the multiple open connection to the Microsoft SQL Server.
When I log-in to the website, open a connection, and when I navigate to the Home and go to view the account info, or go to change a password, each navigation to a Controller open a new connection to the database. I verify the open connection in sys.sysprocesses table. Does The template have a logic error? The original template with Entity Framework handle connection well? I have to rework the original logic in the template with Identity 2.0?

Comment: What do you expect ? all of your transactions happen using the same connection ? every request will create/dispose the context/connection created through that context.